# How do I get a Hasura/Strawberry Shake project to build when query has Date and date types?

Tags: graphql, hasura, strawberryshake

We have a query that accepts two arguments, one of type `Date` and one of type `date`--something like this:

```
query TestQ($deadline: date!, $another_deadline: Date!) { ... }
```

When I attempt to build the project containing this query, it fails on an "already contains a definition for" exception because the autogenerated HasuraClient.Client class contains duplicate fields (I'm guessing one for each of the date parameters above):

```
    private readonly global::StrawberryShake.Serialization.IInputValueFormatter _dateFormatter;
    private readonly global::StrawberryShake.Serialization.IInputValueFormatter _dateFormatter;


// and in constructor:
      _dateFormatter = serializerResolver.GetInputValueFormatter("date");
      _dateFormatter = serializerResolver.GetInputValueFormatter("Date");
```

I also see:

```
private readonly global::StrawberryShake.Serialization.ILeafValueParser<global::System.String, global::System.DateTime> _dateParser;
 private readonly global::StrawberryShake.Serialization.ILeafValueParser<global::System.String, global::System.String> _stringParser;

//and in the constructor:
 _dateParser = serializerResolver.GetLeafValueParser<global::System.String, global::System.String>("date") ?? throw new global::System.ArgumentException("No serializer for type `date` found.");
 _dateParser = serializerResolver.GetLeafValueParser<global::System.String, global::System.DateTime>("Date") ?? throw new global::System.ArgumentException("No serializer for type `Date` found.");
```

I've tried adding various custom serializers by inheriting from `StrawberryShake.Serialization.ScalarSerializer`, including:

```
public class DbDateSerializer : ScalarSerializer<string , DateTime>
```

and following the instructions on the [ChilliCream site](https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/v13/scalars#any-or-json), but nothing is working.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should proceed?